# Custom HTML structure in wp_list_categories

Tags: php, theme-development, categories

I am trying to accomplish an Ajax navigation for the categories and for that I need the code to look something like:

```
<ul>
  <li data-level="1">Parent Category</li>
  <li data-level="1">Parent Category
    <ul class="children">
       <li class="sub-category" data-level="2">Subcategory
       <ul class="children">
         <li class="sub-sub-category" data-level="3">Sub Subcategory</li>
       </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I already have a walker defined that creates something similar, also adding a div around the children ul and a class to the categories that do not contain any children categories. It works fine for the first level of subcategories but I got stuck there and can't seem to be able to create the next level of subcategories properly. This is the walker I have:

```
class Navigation_Catwalker extends Walker_Category {

// Configure the start of each level
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "";
}

// Configure the end of each level
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "";
}

// Configure the start of each element
function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {

    // Set the category name and slug as a variables for later use
    $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
    $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
    $cat_slug = esc_attr( $category->slug );
    $n_depth = $depth + 1;
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy );
    if(count($termchildren)===0){
        $class .=  'i-dont-have-kids';
    }
    // Configure the output for the top list element and its URL
    if ( $depth === 0 ) {
        $link = '<a class="parent-category-dropdown" href="#"' . '>' . $cat_name . '</a>';
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\t<li class='parent-category $class " . $cat_slug . "' data-level='$n_depth'>$link\n$indent<div class='children'><ul>\n<li class='parent-name' data-level='$n_depth'>" . $cat_name . "</li>";
    }

    // Configure the output for lower level list elements and their URL's
    if ( $depth === 1 ) {
        $link = '<a href="#"' . '>' . $cat_name . '</a>';
        $output .= "\t<li class='sub-category $class' data-level='$n_depth'>$link\n";
    } 
    if( $depth > 1) {
      $link = '<a href="#"' . '>' . $cat_name . '</a>';
       $output .= "\n<li class='sub-category $class' data-level='$n_depth'>$link\n";
    }


}

// Configure the end of each element
function end_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    if ( $depth === 0 ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n</div>\n";
    }
    if ( $depth > 0 ) {
        $output .= "</li>";
    }

}

}
```

Anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone finds this someday I was able to solve this and I used tis walker:

```
class Navigation_Catwalker extends Walker_Category {

// Configure the start of each level
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "";
}

// Configure the end of each level
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "";
}

// Configure the start of each element
function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {

    // Set the category name and slug as a variables for later use
    $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
    $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
    $cat_slug = esc_attr( $category->slug );
    $n_depth = $depth + 1;
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy );
    $class = '';
    if(count($termchildren)===0){
        $class .=  'i-dont-have-kids';
    }

    // Configure the output for the top list element and its URL
    if ( count($termchildren)>0) {
        $link = '<a class="parent-category-dropdown" href="#"' . '>' . $cat_name . '</a>';
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\t<li class='parent-category $class " . $cat_slug . "' data-level='$n_depth'>$link\n$indent<div class='children'><ul>\n<li class='parent-name'>" . $cat_name . "</li>";
    }

    // Configure the output for lower level list elements and their URL's
    if ( count($termchildren)===0) {
        $link = '<a href="#">' . $cat_name . '</a>';
        $output .= "\t<li class='sub-category $class' data-level='$n_depth'>$link\n";
    } 
    // if( $depth > 1) {
    //   $link = '<a href="#">' . $cat_name . '</a>';
    //    $output .= "\n<li class='sub-category $class' data-level='$n_depth'>$link\n";
    // }
}

// Configure the end of each element
function end_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0,$args = array()) {
  $termchildren = get_term_children( $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy );
    if (count($termchildren)>0) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n</div>\n";
    }
    if (count($termchildren)===0 ) {
        $output .= "</li>";
    }

}

}
```